# Website over-resizing elements

Tags: html, css, size

I have a website here: [RedstoneGaming](http://www.redstonegaming.com/) and as I make the browser smaller/larger... it just decides to not resize elements at the correct percentile/viewport-part. As a result, it just looks undesirable on mobile devices. Ex: the icons at the bottom should never go into hidden view, but when I resize it certain ways it decides to hide under the bottom of the screen.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>RG - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <p class="title">
      <a class="option side-option" href="whatido.html">What I Do</a> 
      <a class="option side-option" href="products.html">Products</a> 
      <a class="option current" style="font-size: 4vmax;" href="index.html">RedstoneGaming</a> 
      <a class="option side-option" href="updates.html">Updates</a> 
      <a class="option side-option" href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" style="width: 90vw;height: 80vh ">
    <p class="text" align="center" style="font-size:6vmax; line-height:0;">Welcome to the Website!</p>
    <p class="text" align="center" style="font-size:2vmax;padding-left:15vmax;padding-right:15vmax;">This website was made for the purpose of my YouTube Channel and coding products. On the site I will have updates on streams, videos, giveaways, etc. To learn more, go and visit the &#39;About Me&#39; tab to learn about why I created a YouTube Channel,
      who I am, and my schedule for the future.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p align="center" style="font-size:4vmax; line-height:0;" class="text">What's Going On?</p>
    <p class="text" align="center" style="font-size:2vmax;padding-left:15vmax;padding-right:15vmax;">Below is the area where I will have the latest events embbed directly into the site just for you!</p>
    <div style="overflow-y: hidden;width: 90%;height: 45%; margin-bottom: 2%;" class="content">
      <p align="center" class="text" style="font-size: 2vmax;color: grey;top:50%;bottom: 50%;">No events have been posted..... Yet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn1kMRRSG8-QdRWcaK7BgIw">
      <img class="ScMedia" alt="Click here to go to my YouTube channel." src="http://www.redstonegaming.com/Images/Icons/youtube.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/thatredstonegt/">
      <img class="ScMedia" alt="" src="http://www.redstonegaming.com/Images/Icons/twitter.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="ScMedia" alt="" src="http://www.redstonegaming.com/Images/Icons/google+.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="ScMedia" alt="" src="http://www.redstonegaming.com/Images/Icons/skype.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="ScMedia" alt="" src="http://www.redstonegaming.com/Images/Icons/instagram.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="ScMedia" alt="" src="http://www.redstonegaming.com/Images/Icons/facebook.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: Tann;
      src: url("TannenbergFett.ttf");
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Space;
      src: url("Spaceport_2006.ttf");
    }
    html {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    body {
      height: 99%;
      width: 99%;
      background-color: #222222;
      background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #2b2b2b 0%, #2b2b2b 10%, #222222 0%, #222222 50%) 0 / 15px 15px;
    }
    .header {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .ScMedia {
      height: 3.5vmax;
      z-index: 6;
      margin: .5% .5% .5% .5%;
      float: right;
    }
    .footer {
      margin-left: 5%;
      margin-right: 5%;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes anim {
      from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #b30000, 0 0 20px #b30000, 0 0 30px #b30000, 0 0 40px #b30000, 0 0 70px #b30000, 0 0 80px #b30000, 0 0 100px #b30000, 0 0 150px #b30000;
      }
      to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #b30000, 0 0 10px #b30000, 0 0 15px #b30000, 0 0 20px #b30000, 0 0 35px #b30000, 0 0 40px #b30000, 0 0 50px #b30000, 0 0 75px #b30000;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes anim {
      from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #b30000, 0 0 20px #b30000, 0 0 30px #b30000, 0 0 40px #b30000, 0 0 70px #b30000, 0 0 80px #b30000, 0 0 100px #b30000, 0 0 150px #b30000;
      }
      to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #b30000, 0 0 10px #b30000, 0 0 15px #b30000, 0 0 20px #b30000, 0 0 35px #b30000, 0 0 40px #b30000, 0 0 50px #b30000, 0 0 75px #b30000;
      }
    }
    @keyframes anim {
      from {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #b30000, 0 0 20px #b30000, 0 0 30px #b30000, 0 0 40px #b30000, 0 0 70px #b30000, 0 0 80px #b30000, 0 0 100px #b30000, 0 0 150px #b30000;
      }
      to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 5px #b30000, 0 0 10px #b30000, 0 0 15px #b30000, 0 0 20px #b30000, 0 0 35px #b30000, 0 0 40px #b30000, 0 0 50px #b30000, 0 0 75px #b30000;
      }
    }
    p.title {
      z-index: 5;
      margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Tann;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    a.option {
      text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      color: #fff;
      padding-left: 2%;
      padding-right: 2%;
    }
    a.current {
      -webkit-animation: anim 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      -moz-animation: anim 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      animation: anim 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    }
    p.title a:hover {
      color: #ff9999;
    }
    .side-option {
      font-size: 2vmax;
      ;
    }
    p.text {
      opacity: 1;
      font-family: Space;
      z-index: 50;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .content {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 25px;
      margin-left: 5%;
      margin-right: 5%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      position: relative
    }
    .chunk {} .video {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
width: 4%;
height: auto;
```

to `.ScMedia`

This will reduce the image as you re-size the screen.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/LtLnvn4k/)

Comment: This helps, but I would like to be able to resize it any way, shape, or form and it still be presentable.

Comment: Then you should be looking at `media queries` http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. You can define rules for each screen size.

Comment: Oh! Like for mobile, desktop, tablet, etc?

Comment: Yes. An example here. https://www.toptal.com/designers/responsive/introduction-to-responsive-web-design-pseudo-elements-media-queries